# Workbooks.Open returns different file than Filename

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am having the strangest problem. I was writing the below code on my laptop the other day and it worked fine. Now, I am testing it on my desktop and it's stopped working.

First, here's my code

```
Dim oApp As Application
Dim oWb As Workbook

Set oApp = New Application
oApp.Visible = True
Set oWb = oApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\myFile.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

debug.print oWb.name
'returns "SOLVER.XLAM"
' "SOLVER.XLAM" is not "myFile.xlsx'

debug.print oApp.Workbooks.Count
'returns 1

debug.print oApp.Workbooks(1).name
'returns "myFile.xlsx"
```

Now, I know that solver is an add in, and it gets loaded in the new application upon creating it... but how does it perform this switcheroo? I can still get to the correct file, but I don't want to risk it on the coincidence that there is only 1 file in my Application object (or that the first file is the one I loaded)

#### Additional Info

I am calling executing this macro from within an excel instance and I wish to open a separate excel instance and then open particular workbook (`"C:\myFile.xlsx"`) inside that other instance.

The key problem I'm having is that when I open the other instance and then add the workbook and set it to my oWb variable... somehow, when I later call that oWb variable it refers to something different from what I had set it to.

```
'This is how it makes me feel:
Dim x As Integer
x = 5

Debug.Print x
' 12
```

Comment: why the `Dim oApp as Application` and `Set oApp...` Is this code not inside an XL environment VBE editor?

Comment: +1 on Scott's question. Where are you calling the code from?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: Your answer was correct. Why did you delete it? :)

Comment: It must be from inside xl given `Set oApp = New Application`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I guess I wasn't 100% sure it would solve the problem and wanted to wait for the OP's response. But, alas, I undeleted it :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman : this is being run from inside an excel application, yes. With the idea of opening another excel application instance.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you just refine your code a bit to ensure you are doing exactly what you want, you will be fine. Since it's unclear whether you are calling the code from within Excel or another MS Office Application, I placed to subs below.

Run this if running it in Excel:

```
Option Explicit

Sub insideXL()

Dim oWb As Workbook
Set oWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\myFile.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

Debug.Print oWb.Name
Debug.Print Workbooks.Count
Debug.Print Workbooks(1).Name

oWb.Close false

Set oWb = Nothing    

End Sub
```

Run this if running in another program. I use early binding, but you could use late binding as well, if you wish:

```
Sub outsideXL()
'make sure Microsoft Excel X.X Object Library is checked in Tools > References

Dim oApp As Excel.Application
Set oApp = New Excel.Application

Dim oWb As Excel.Workbook
Set oWb = oApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\myFile.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

oApp.Visible = True

Debug.Print oWb.Name
Debug.Print Workbooks.Count
Debug.Print Workbooks(1).Name

oWb.Close = True
Set oWb = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing    

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, thanks for the info. I think my question is not specific enough (I'm headed back to edit it now). I'm having a situation where I am opening "myFile.xlxs" and setting that to the oWb variable... but somewhere along the line  my oWb variable ends up pointing to a different workbook. Circling back to add clarity now

Comment: @MikePG -> I read your updated post. 3 things **1)** do you really need to open another XL app within an already existing XL? If so, why? **2)** did you try my suggestion for running it outside of XL, specifically designating `oApp` as an `Excel.Application`?  **3)** You say `when I later call that oWb variable' -> what happens between the time you set oWb and you use it? Can you post that part of the code?

Comment: I don't see how this answer solves the issue... Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426974/com-bug-opening-a-workbook-twice-leads-to-broken-reference

Answer (score 1):

I found that this (which worked in 2007):

```
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True)
```

needs to be written

```
excel.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True)
wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook
```

for 2010

Comment: Very strange. I haven't used 2010, yet. Are you intentionally omitting `SET` from your code? I would expect you'd be able to assign a workbook object directly without having to assign it arbitrarily (as in "hopefully the right one") after opening. Perhaps if you write the first line as?

`SET wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True)`

Comment: @Mike PG I Didn't say so explicitly, but it's VB.Net, not VBScript

Comment: Can confirm, this works (and may be necessary) in Office 2016 as well.

In my case, I was opening a spreadsheet with links. The call to Workbooks.Open was not returning the workbook corresponding with the path I supplied, but rather one of the linked spreadsheets. Totally logical......

Anyways, simply calling Workbooks.Open and then grabbing Excel.ActiveWorkbook did the trick for me. Thanks @smirkingman!