# COM bug? Opening a workbook twice leads to broken reference

Tags: excel, vba, com

Credit to [fuglede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5085211/fuglede) for bringing this to my attention:

Is this a COM bug?

I open Excel workbook A, then open workbook B (both of which have a bit of identifying text in cell A1).

Then I attempt to open workbook A again and save that reference in a new variable `a2`. But `a2` now points to workbook B!

This exact same behavior is reproduced in Python using win32com. So this isn't a VBA issue specifically, bur rather a COM issue more generally. (i.e. presumably also in C# etc., though not confirmed yet.)

What is going on?

VBA code:  (Python win32com code is similar.)

```vb
'Open a couple of workbooks
Dim a As Workbook, b As Workbook, a2 As Workbook
Debug.Print "Set a = a.xlsx..."
Set a = Application.Workbooks.Open("H:\a.xlsx")
Debug.Print "a:  " & a.Name
Debug.Print "Set b = b.xlsx..."
Set b = Application.Workbooks.Open("H:\b.xlsx")
Debug.Print "b:  " & b.Name
Debug.Print "a:  " & a.Name

'Attempt to re-open workbook a.xlsx and keep reference in a new variable
Debug.Print "Set a2 = a.xlsx..."
Set a2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("H:\a.xlsx") '<---- should open A, right?
Debug.Print "a2: " & a2.Name '<------------------------------------------------ !!!
Debug.Print "b:  " & b.Name
Debug.Print "a:  " & a.Name

'Read workbook content
Debug.Print "Contents of cell A1..."
Debug.Print "From a:  " & a.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Debug.Print "From b:  " & b.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value 
Debug.Print "From a2: " & a2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value '<------------- !!!
```

Resulting output in the Immediate window: (similar in Python console)

```
Set a = a.xlsx...
a:  a.xlsx
Set b = b.xlsx...
b:  b.xlsx
a:  a.xlsx
Set a2 = a.xlsx...
a2: b.xlsx           <--------------- WTF?!
b:  b.xlsx
a:  a.xlsx
Contents of cell A1...
From a:  I'm in A
From b:  I'm in B
From a2: I'm in B    <--------------- WTF?!
```

Comment: Whether the intended behavior of not, it certainly is not the most natural way to read the documentation, currently available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel, which states that the returned value is "A Workbook object that represents the opened workbook.".

Comment: Key word: "the".

Comment: Somewhere in .Open() there is code to match the file name to a workbook already in the workbooks collection and if one is found to return the same reference. It seems that this code is bugged and it always effectively "falls through" & erroneously returns the last opened workbook reference for any workbook already open (i.e. within workbooks).

Comment: It's certainly not a COM bug, issue is only related to Excel. Not sure it's a "bug" either. Excel is not a programming library, it's an end-user tool. You should see the object model as live thing, resulting of the UI, not the reverse. Anything can happen on it depending on the UI/user context, SDI/MDI, also 3rd parties, macro, etc. It can also vary if you run from Excel or from outside (more async, move living), if its UI is visible or not and on its version (2013+). This is an old story: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019981/workbooks-open-returns-different-file-than-filename

Comment: "It's not a bug. It's a feature." ?

Comment: The problem is worse than the original post, even. When multiple calls to `Workbooks.Open()` happen for the same workbook, previous references are completely invalidated by the later calls. https://gist.github.com/Neuroboy23/bec84b82dc37568c79434a2f0b215a35

Comment: @MichaelGunter Can't reproduce. The code you link to works as expected at my end. (However, something like you describe does happen when opening workbooks from the Immediate window.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug indeed. Apparently this line:

```vb
Set a2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("H:\a.xlsx")
```

(unexpectedly) works the same as

```vb
Application.Workbooks.Open "H:\a.xlsx"
Set a2 = ActiveWorkbook
```

Because a.xlsx is already open b.xlsx is (and remains) the activeworkbook, so then a2 gets a reference to b.xlsx.

In order to prevent the problem from happening you should test whether a workbook is already open in Excel before trying to open it again.

Comment: It seems more complicated than that: I tried opening workbooks `a.xlsx`, `b.xlsx`, `c.xlsx`, activating `a`, and opening `c.xlsx` again. In this case, `Open` returned the `b` workbook which was neither the active workbook, nor the most recently opened one.

Comment: Definitely worth an Excel UserVoice issue.

Comment: I agree, this is not correct behaviour. Though I stand by my comment that you should be testing whether the workbook isn't already open and act accordingly.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in `pywin32` with Excel 2007. When I `Workbooks.Open` `1.xlsx`, `2.xlsx`, `3.xlsx`, then `1.xlsx` again, the order of workbooks in `Workbooks` changes from 1-2-3 to 2-3-1, but `Open` returns the correct workbook.